# Font Previews in Win Forms Using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, fonts, preview

First of all sorry for my poor English.
I want to create a desktop application using WinForms or WPF using C#. This app must work in same way like http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=115&text=Font+Test site. User will enter a sample text and I will show this text in different fonts installed in this computer in list view or grid. Could you please guide me what is the best practice for doing it?

Comment: You need to at least post a reasonable attempt a solving this yourself.  One simple solution would just to loop through the installed fonts on the machine and by doing so add an entry to the listview, there are many ways to go about doing that.

Answer (score 2):

In WPF it's a XAML only thing:

```
xmlns:media="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Media;assembly=PresentationCore"
```

```
<TextBox Name="sampleTextTB" Text="Some fox jumped over some other animal, i think"/>
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Static media:Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=sampleTextTB, Path=Text}"
                       FontFamily="{Binding}" FontSize="20"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string text = textBox1.Text;
            FontFamily ff = GetRandomFont();
            Font fnt = new Font(ff, 12, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic);
            textBox2.Font = fnt;
            textBox3.Font = fnt;
            textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;
            textBox3.Text = textBox1.Text;
        }

        private FontFamily GetRandomFont()
        {
                FontFamily[] ff = System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families;
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int num = rnd.Next(ff.Length);
                return ff[num];
        }
```